# Save continuous data printed in a bash shell in a file

Tags: sensor, bash

we are working with a Sensor (Sensirion SDC41) connected to a Raspberry Pi 4.

We have a .c file provided by Sensirion, that, when called in the bash shell, it outputs a continuous flux of data (one measurement every 5 seconds) and prints it in the bash shell.

We would like to save the output, continuously printed in the bash shell, somewhere. Data should be saved at every measurement, so if the process is interrupted, we have the data saved up to that point.

The process that generate data should not be interrupted to save the data in a file (such as a txt file).
Any idea on how to do it?

I hope everything is clear.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The Pi is irrelevant to this question (which is general Linux).  I suggest you look at command line redirection and/or the tee command. `man bash`, `man tee`

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks detail, but a general answer may go like this:

1. In your script, when you call the `" .c file provided by Sensirion"`, add a `redirect`. If you wish to use the same file & add to it, use the "append" form of the redirect. If you want to overwrite any contents, use the "overwrite" form. For example, the output is to go to a file "/home/pi/mySensirionData":

```bsh
# overwrite redirect: 
/path/to/SensironExecutable > /home/pi/mySensirionData

# append redirect: 
/path/to/SensironExecutable >> /home/pi/mySensirionData
```

So - `>` overwrites the target file, `>>` appends to the target file

And if it's important that the process not be interrupted, you could start the script using [`nohup`](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/); e.g.:

```bsh
$ nohup /path/to/SensironExecutable & 
  [1] 1234 
$
```

`nohup` will keep your job running even if your shell is terminated, logout, etc. Handily, the output (`1234` in the example above) is the PID (process ID) of your script. Note: this is **not** the PID of `SensironExecutable`, it is the PID of the bash script in which you called `SensironExecutable`. For more details on job control, read [this tutorial](https://www.howtogeek.com/440848/how-to-run-and-control-background-processes-on-linux/).

Comment: Thanks to both Seamus and Joan. We will look into your suggestions!

Comment: @RobMatALMA: It seems your question has been closed for being "off-topic". Please understand that the boundary between "on-topic" and "off-topic" in RPi SE is **not** a crisp or clear line, but rather more of a subjective judgment. This is particularly true for RPi SE because **a:** the RPi OS is Linux,  **b:** RPi activities frequently involve Electronics and **c:** Linux & Electronics are also SE sites! Also know that `Closed` only means that your question cannot receive answers from other contributors here, but my answer can still be edited, and AFAIK, comments still work as before closure.